# Regex interpretation and javascript's replace function. Why do we need the capture group?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var cleaned_input = input.replace(/(\s{2,}\n|\t)/g," ")
```

I have this line. This regex seems to replace any space of two or more, any newline, and any tab globally with just a single space. But why do I need the capture group? What is captured?

Comment: In your regex captured group isn't needed

Comment: Just note that this regex will replace any "space or two followed by a newline" or "tab", see here: https://regex101.com/r/vV2eF9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does replace by a single space all "contiguous spaces (2 or more) followed by a line-feed" OR "individual tabs".

The capturing group is unnecessary in this case, but I believe it was put there because of a false assumption that or (`|`) statements always need to be within parenthesis.